# Como reemplazar en una cadena a enviar por un valor de una variable donde hay caracteres de escape y doble comillas

Tags: arduino

Tengo este problema y no se en que foro corresponde hacer esta pregunta y encontrar una solución real.

Tengo un envío de información json para una notificacion push

```
String data = "{" ;
  data = data + " \"to\": \"d5DAPA91bGk_zz-GdV8_V0iZnetFmaBWwqXgZB62ev0Z3B\",";
  data = data + "\"notification\": {" ;
  data = data + "\"body\": \"deteccion movimiento\"," ;
  data = data + "\"title\" : \"Alarma\" " ;
  data = data + "} }" ;
  Serial.println(data);

Y obtengo como resultado, que si funciona :
  { "to": "d5DAPA91bGk_zz-GdV8_V0iZnetFmaBWwqXgZB62ev0Z3B","notification": {"body": "Motion detected","title" : "Alarm"} }

Pero necesito que el valor de destino sea de la forma  que se
toma de una variable recuperada de la memoria y que se reemplace. Ejemplo:

valor="AL35DAPA9husd99d734ddsd'x42FfE7tsos";

{ "to": [valor] ,"notification": {"body": "Motion detected","title" : "Alarm"} }
```

donde en `[valor]` tiene que ser reemplazado por lo definido previamente y debe ser insertado despues de `"to"`:
y antes de la notificacion

Todo indicaría que debería haber "comilla" de inicio antes de poner el valor de la variable y "comilla" final. 
Y la realidad es que siempre sale el texto `[valor]` y  nunca la  equivalencia que se ha definido.

Debería ser finalmente :

```
  { "to": "AL35APA9husd99d734ddsd'x42FfE7tsos" ,"notification": {"body": "Motion detected","title" : "Alarm"} }
```

Como se resuelve esto?

Answer (score 0):

Si la variable `valor` es de tipo `String`, en donde armas la cadena `data` deberías reemplazar la línea

```
data = data + " \"to\": \"d5DAPA91bGk_zz-GdV8_V0iZnetFmaBWwqXgZB62ev0Z3B\",";
```

por algo similar a

```
data = data + " \"to\": \"" + valor + "\",";
```

No se me ocurre por qué te mostraría el texto literal `[valor]`, de cualquier manera.